# JBOSS extjs configuration

Tags: extjs, jboss6.x

I am developing an application using **ExtJS** where all related `ExtJS` file I have to keep in individual web app to be referred.

I want it to configure in `JBOSS 6.1` as a module and then referred by any web app in my local.

Is there any way to achieve this.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go would be to follow the  "production process" that Sencha defined where you put into a single .js file all your defined classes plus the classes of the framework you are actually using. This is way faster.

[http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?230650-How-to-package-(minify)-an-extjs-4-application](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?230650-How-to-package-%28minify%29-an-extjs-4-application)

Although if you really want accessible the full framework for some(stubborn manager :P) reason. You can always create a simple Web application with ExtJs inside of it and refer to the classes from other web applications ...

ExtJs.war --> contains the full framework and nothing else

MyCoolEnterpriseApp --> in the html refers to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ExtJs/extjs-4.2.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```